# Which city in Austria is more modern: Graz or Linz?

Tags: austria

Which city in Austria is more cleaner: Graz or Linz? Which one is more crowded? Which city feels like a modern western European city? Which one has more natural beauty? And, which one has more homeless people than the other?

I want to visit only one city. Here, in Poland, I find that, cities look poorer. I don't like poor cities. Is Graz going to be the same? I think Linz is more mountainous, and, looks rich and naturally beautiful. From some Google images, Graz looks cheaper and crowded.

For example, I live in Wroclaw, Poland. This city has much less crowd than Warsaw. This is a clean city. But, development work in progression is visible everywhere. At the center of the city, it looks like an old city. It looks like, buildings need repair works.

Comment: Too many (mostly opinion based) questions at once. It's also not clear what your motivations are for asking (and how that relates to travel)

Comment: @CMaster, My motivation is, I want to visit only one city. Here, in Poland, I find that, cities look poorer. I don't like poor cities. Is Graz going to be the same? I think Linz is more mountainous, and, looks rich and naturally beautiful. Graz looks cheaper though.

Comment: Graz might be cheaper for Austria and has a bit of student life and some modern architecture left over from its 2003 stint as “European Capital of Culture” but overall it's not a big city and is still rich and picturesque. No need to worry about crowds, homelessness or derelict buildings.

Comment: I know both places and vote for Linz, but mostly for the food and the epic scenery and architecture.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based.

Answer (score -1):

Linz is located in the centre of Europe, lying on the Paris–Budapest west–east axis and the Malmö–Trieste north–south axis. The Danube is the main tourism and transport connection that runs through the city.

Comment: I am not convinced the "axes" are a strong argument. After all, [Graz evidently lies right on the Paris-Brașov West-East axis and the Malmö-Zagreb North-South axis](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=500x500&path=Paris|Linz|Budapest&path=Malm%C3%B6%7CLinz|Trieste&path=color:red|Paris|Graz|Brasov&path=color:red|Malm%C3%B6%7CGraz|Zagreb&markers=color:blue|label:L|Linz&markers=color:red|label:G|Graz).